# java.lang.ClassCastException on Proxy creation

Tags: java, dynamic-proxy

My goal is to create an instance from a `class` that implements an `interface` and extends another `class`.

...Entity annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Entity {

    String visibileName();

}
```

...implements`IEventDesignDialog`

```
      public class EventDesignDialog implements IEventDesignDialog{

        private String show;
        private String dateAndTimeDisplayFormat;
        private String eventType;


        @Entity(visibileName = "Show")
        public String getShow() {
            return this.show;
        }

        @Entity(visibileName = "Date And Time display format")
        public String getDateAndTimeDisplayFormat() {
            return this.dateAndTimeDisplayFormat;
        }

        @Entity(visibileName = "Event Type")
        public String getEventType() {
            System.out.println("get event type method invokde successfully");
            return this.eventType;
        }
}
```

`IEventDesignDialog` interface:

```
public interface IEventDesignDialog extends IPage{

    public String getShow();

    public String getDateAndTimeDisplayFormat();

    public String getEventType();


}
```

`IPage` interface:

```
public interface IPage {

}
```

Dynamic proxy implementation:

```
public class IPageProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    private List<Method> entityMethods;



    private Class <? extends IPage> screenClazz;

    public IPageProxy(final Class <? extends IPage> screenClazz) {
        entityMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        getEntityAnnotatedMethods(screenClazz);
        // Accept the real implementation to be proxied
        this.screenClazz = screenClazz;
    }


    /**
     * create an page instance
     * @param type
     * @param
     * @return
     * @throws InstantiationException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     */
    public static IPage getInstance(final Class<? extends IPage> type)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        List<Class<?>> interfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        interfaces.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getInterfaces()));

        return (IPage) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                type.getClassLoader(),
                findInterfaces(type),
                new IPageProxy(type)
             );

        /*return (IPage) Proxy.newProxyInstance(type.getClassLoader(),
               interfaces.toArray(new Class<?>[interfaces.size()])
                , new IPageProxy(type));*/
    }


    /**
     * get all methods that annotated with @Entity annotation
     * and add it for entityMethods array List
     * @param screenClazz
     */
    private void getEntityAnnotatedMethods(final Class <? extends IPage>  screenClazz) {
        // Scan each interface method for the specific annotation
        // and save each compatible method
        for (final Method m : screenClazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)) {
                entityMethods.add(m);
            }
        }
    }


    static Class<?>[] findInterfaces(final Class<? extends IPage> type) {
        Class<?> current = type;

        do {
            final Class<?>[] interfaces = current.getInterfaces();

            if (interfaces.length != 0) {
                return interfaces;
            }
        } while ((current = current.getSuperclass()) != Object.class);

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The type does not implement any interface");
    }



    @Override
    public Object invoke(
            final Object proxy,
            final Method method,
            final Object[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        // A method on MyInterface has been called!
        // Check if we need to go call it directly or if we need to
        // execute something else before!


        if (entityMethods.contains(method)) {
            // The method exist in our to-be-proxied list
            // Execute something and the call it
            // ... some other things
            System.out.println("Something else");
        }

        // Invoke original method
        return method.invoke(screenClazz, args);
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            ((EventDesignDialog)getInstance(EventDesignDialog.class)).getEventType();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends IPage> T getInstance(final Class<? extends IPage> type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return (T) IPageProxy.getInstance(type);
    }

}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2 cannot be cast to abc.EventDesignDialog
    at abc.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: The proxy that is created is not a `Screen` but rather a class that implements all of `Screen`s `interface`s, so they are not equal. That's why you get that exception

Comment: I remember we discussed about Dynamic Proxies a while ago, I see you're using them frequently!

Comment: yes, I'm investigating this type of code writing. actually, I'm learning how to use this feature.

Comment: @AliTaha that's good, it's an interesting topic. Let me know if you need other clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **extending** `Screen`, which means it isn't an `interface`.
Dynamic Proxies work only if a base `interface` is present in the hierarchy.

```
interfaces.size() == 0
```

Thus the proxy can't implement any `interface`, and obviously it isn't part of the `Screen` hierarchy.

---

If `Screen` was an `interface`, your method is still too complex. This

```
public static Screen getInstance(Class<? extends Screen> type)
```

is sufficient.

---

You still receive an exception because

```
Class#getInterfaces
```

returns the `interface`s which are implemented by **this** class.

That means if you invoke it on `EventDesignDialog.class`, it will return an empty array.
That means if you invoke it on `EntityDesignDialog.class`, still it will return an empty array.
When invoking it on `Screen.class`, it will return

```
[IPage.class]
```

You need to loop the hierarchy with

```
Class#getSuperclass
```

until you find a suitable `interface`.

A possible implementation might look like

```
static Class<?>[] findInterfaces(final Class<?> type) {
    Class<?> current = type;

    do {
        final Class<?>[] interfaces = current.getInterfaces();

        if (interfaces.length != 0) {
            return interfaces;
        }
    } while ((current = current.getSuperclass()) != Object.class);

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The type does not implement any interface");
}
```

which means you need to change your code to

```
return (IPage) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
              type.getClassLoader(),
              findInterfaces(type),
              new IPageProxy(type)
           );
```

But, being that you already know the result will be an `IPage` proxy, you can just

```
return (IPage) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
              type.getClassLoader(),
              new Class[] { IPage.class },
              new IPageProxy(type)
           );
```

---

Here

```
public static IPage getInstance(final Class<? extends IPage> type)
```

you're returning an `IPage`, but here

```
((EventDesignDialog)getInstance(EventDesignDialog.class))
```

you're trying to **downcast** it, which means you're trying to cast it to a more specific type. This isn't possible as the Proxy isn't of the type `EventDesignDialog`, but it just implements your `IPage` interface.

Being that Dynamic Proxies are interface-based, you'll be forced to deal with interfaces.
Trying to cast to concrete classes will always throw an exception.

If you need an `IEventDesignDialog`, you need a new Proxy specifically for it.

Comment: Screen class implements IPage interface, now that is its signature:                              public static IPage getInstance(Class<? extends IPage> type)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException                                          same exception thrown : java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11 cannot be cast to com.abc.IPage

Comment: @AliTaha btw, if you already know that IPage is the wanted interface. Just pass it directly with `new Class[] { IPage.class }`

Comment: I need to create instances from classes that implement Ipage :)

Comment: I added full code implementation above, it still throws an exception, can you please show how to fix it?

Comment: @AliTaha see updared answer.